# Designing object oriented systems / GUIs

Tags: java, oop, architecture

I have a pretty large project in front of me that I intend to develop using Java. I am no pro at Java but I have used it before and look forward to learning more about it.

I have started work on the project but as I continue working I realize that I keep over-looking different requirements of the project as a whole or different things that I could implement more efficiently with better object design.

For those of you that architect object oriented systems often, what approaches have you all found to make your end result(s) work more effectively and efficiently? Ie: is there a step by step procedure that you use to determine the architecture of your system like

1. Draw out requirements
2. Group requirements by similar interests
3. Map dependencies
4. etc etc

Any pointers that you all could offer as to effective ways to architect object oriented systems would be appreciated.

**NOTE** - This is a gui-based application. As such I was planning on taking an MVC approach (model is MySQL database, controller is code-behind class for GUI class, view is GUI class). If there are specific techniques for building object oriented systems for GUIs as well please leave them here.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use Test-Driven Development - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development

Comment: The concentration of test-driven development seems to be for quick development cycles. While I think this would be helpful, from an architectural standpoint this doesn't seem to say much about OO architecture.

Comment: Consider Griffon. Swing is already MVC, are you wanting to lay something else on top of that, or? There's no step-by-step procedure--it's an iterative process and highly dependent on the requirements.

Comment: Yes I guess I didn't need to specify I was using MVC if I was already using Swing. Agreed that it's an iterative process but from a high enough view point there must be some similarities between different project approaches regardless of requirements and content.

Comment: @DaveNewton:  I agree that Spring itself, internally, is MVC.  However, as a whole, Spring only represents the VC of your application.  The model will be based on requirements and likely simple POJO's.  The OP will have to convert the application's model to Swing's model.  They are not the same (except for something incredibly trivial).  Swing itself is MVC but only a part of his architecture but that does not make the overall application MVC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a very quick stab at writing down what I do (sort of) on my own personal-sized projects. (This may not be exactly what you were after but it might help.  Some parts might not be relevant):

1. Think about **what it is I'm trying to achieve** with the software project and **my motivation** for doing it.  Is it just to learn a language, technology or concept?  Is it to build a very polished program as well as I can?  Is it to impress someone? Is it because I have to or its a means to an end? Is it to build my skills? Is it purely for fun?
2. Make sure I've got a **clear idea of the main features** it should have ("for this version" is a great line I keep giving myself)
3. **Write out** as many **requirements** as I can until they don't come so easy ( I do this on a wiki I run at home ).  It doesn't have to be a whole bunch.  I'm looking to feel like I've got ~80% of the ones that really matter.
4. If I don't know by this stage, **work out** some sort of idea of what **process and tools** (methodology) I'm going to use.  What language, what frameworks etc might be relevant.  If I don't know, I find out.
5. **Iterate the above** until I've got a good enough idea of what I want to build, how i'm going to go about it and using what.
6. **Create** a project in **Visual Paradigm** for UML.
7. Start mucking around **developing use cases** in a **problem domain** analysis UML model
8. **Create** some **static problem domain diagrams**. Just basic class diagrams I'm using UML here but it has nothing to do with software.
9. **Create** some **dynamic problem domain diagrams**. Just basic sequence diagrams. I'm using UML here but it has nothing to do with software.
10. **Iterate** over the **problem domain**.  I usually find developing the problem domain model doesn't take that long before it's pretty stable.  Obviously that will change with increasing scope and complexity.
11. **Create** a solution domain analysis/architecture model and **develop use cases for the solution**.
12. If there is any **UI design** to be done, I'll start thinking about it and **wireframing** here alongside the use cases.
13. **Create** some **static solution domain analysis diagrams** where I try to translate some of the static analysis model into something that looks more like the structure of software without thinking about how it might be implemented.  I start high and work lower, trying to flesh out an architecture.  At this point I'll start looking for obvious structure and places to potentially apply patterns.
14. **Create** some **dynamic solution domain analysis diagrams** where I try to flesh out the static analysis model by seeing if I'm missing anything when I actually try and walkthrough the system. Still keeping an eye open for patterns here.
15. **Create** some **static solution domain design diagrams** where I try to convert the solution analysis model into actual classes and components I want to implement.  I start high and work lower.  Patterns and architecture must start to crystalise here.
16. **Create** some **dynamic solution domain diagrams** where I try to flesh out the static model by seeing if I've missing any classes or functionality.  I find a great deal of important questions get answered at this stage.
17. **Iterate** all steps to the previous iteration point and refine the models until I've got something I'm happy to start implementing.
18. Setup the **build environemnt** (if necessary)
19. **Create a project in the IDE** I'm going to use and **setup version control**.
20. Establish the **build system**
21. **Implement** according to the solution design.
22. **Update** the various **UML models** and diagrams as I encounter unforeseen problems implementing the design.
23. **Perform** whatever manual **validation** I need to (often just ad-hoc system testing to convince myself see if I've satisfied my requirements).
24. **Iterate** the last three steps until the system is valid and I'd be happy to put my initials on the result.
25. Think up the **next features** to add and **iterate** from about step 7!

I guess to summarise, I rely heavily on multiple levels of UML modelling.  There's just no replacement for laying out classes and tracing interaction with entities that I can quickly drag around and connect.  I find the separation of problem and solution domain, and analysis and design models to generally be extremely useful and liberating.

I hope this is of interest to someone.